# How do I stop a Selenium server from an Ant task that I forked from a `java` target?

Tags: java, multithreading, ant, selenium, fork

I have written an Ant target that starts Selenium server, runs my test code, and then... I would like it to stop the forked process (Selenium). How do I keep track of that forked thread that Ant created in order to stop it?

Comment: Many servers come with a command-line shutdown tool (e.g. shutdown.bat/sh for Tomcat and JBoss). I'm not familiar with Selenium, but you can check if it has one as well.

Comment: @Toby - Linux, using eclipse and a text editor.

Comment: I can't remember why I asked that question... :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to shutdown selenium server with a direct web request to

http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

[The http get task will do for this.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was starting to think that I was trying to do something wrong. Do you know how I would send an HTTP request to the Selenium server via Ant?

Comment: There is an Ant task named "get" that can hit a URL.

Comment: or start a OS process and curl/wget it (*shudder*)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the ant target:]

```
 <target name="stop-server">
    <get taskname="selenium-shutdown" src="http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer"
    dest="result.txt" ignoreerrors="true" />
    <echo taskname="selenium-shutdown" message="DGF Errors during shutdown are expected" />
</target>
```